# Codeigniter: Easiest way to make users details grabbed from a data base accessible by methods in any controller or method

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I already asked this question, but in a way that confused people.

So what I want to achieve is this:

I have a method get_user_by_email() and it is used to grab the row from the database table of a user who is logged out.

```
public function get_user_by_email($email_post = '') //post email grabbed from reset password controller
{
if (empty($email_post))
{
    return FALSE;
}
$query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email_post'");
$query->row();

$row = $query->row();
$user_id = $row->{'id'};
$email = $row->{'email'};
$first_name = $row->{'first_name'};
$last_name = $row->{'last_name'};

//e.g. example below is just an example and obviously wouldn't work but the variables are what I use in my mysql querys ...eg. WHERE email = $email etc

return $email;
return $first_name;
return $last_name;
return $user_id;

}
```

The above code doesn't work and I know this but I was giving an example of what I am doing with the data I get from the row.

I just want to some how make this available to my reset_password controller through out, then my confirm_reset_code controller and then finally my create_new_password controller.

How would I do this?

**NEW MODEL**

```
class Get_user_by_email extends CI_Model {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::Ci_Model();

    }

        public function process($email_post = '') //post email grabbed from reset password controller
        {
        if (empty($email_post))
        {
            return FALSE;
        }
        return $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = '$email_post'");

        }

}
```

**NEW CONTROLLER**

```
<?php

class Account extends FH_Controller {
    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();

        $this->load->model('get_user_by_email');


    }

    public function reset_password()
    {
        $this->load->view('reset_password');
        if ($this->get_user_by_email->process($this->input->post('e-mail')))
        {
        $query = $this->get_user_by_email->process();
        print_r($query);



        }
    }

    public function confirm_reset_code()
    {
        $this->load->view('confirm_reset_code');
    }

    public function create_new_password()
    {
        $this->load->view('create_new_password');
    }
}
```

I enter email and nothing is returned to browser.

Comment: I suggest reading the CodeIgnter user guide (http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/index.html) before trying to use CodeIgniter.  This is a model file.

Comment: It is actually still a bit confusing, could you detail exactly what you are trying to accomplish?  your title seems to differ from what you are asking in the question body.

Comment: I always have the manual open but sometimes it's good to seek help else where. I use a combination of both..

Comment: I understand.  I was just saying that what you want to do is the definition of a model file.

Comment: I appreciate the response. I think from all the replies to this post I may have enough to work with and do what I need to do. It's just that I didn't think I would become stuck with a password reset feature after coding a full user sign up, activation and login from scratch..including auto login. I decided not to use a pre-made system because I'm still learning and have learnt much from the mistakes I have made. Some times it really does annoy me though, I have been trying to do this password reset for the last 2 days and I was close to calling it a day.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot return multiple times.  Just make an array, and return that.

Instead of `$row = $query->row();`, use `$row = $query->row_array();`, and then return that array.

This function should be inside a model file, which can be loaded from any controller.

EDIT: Some changes for your new code:

1. `parent::Ci_Model();` should be `parent::__construct();` (Don't mix php5 and php5 constructors)
2. You need to call `row()` or `row_array()` on `$query` to get results.  I suggest you don't return `$query`.
3. `$this->get_user_by_email->process();` should be `$this->Get_user_by_email->process();` (Models start with an uppercase letter)

Comment: Going to give this a shot now. Already created the model so anytime I need those variables I'll call that model method

Comment: I knew that return couldn't be used multiple times the way I did it. I was just trying to give an example of how those variables could be used.

Comment: The row array and row both work but what I want to do is return it at the end of the model method. Then use the data from the array in my controller

Comment: @Psychonetics: Ok.  Are you still stuck?

Comment: I'm afraid so. I have created the get_user_by_email model. I have added that code to this post.

Comment: Think I cracked it. I'll post in a sec

Comment: @Psychonetics: Read my suggestions in the answer.

Comment: I didn't think the upper case thing mattered. Well only when declaring a class name. The way I do it has always worked for me. I guess it's good practice to do it the way you suggested? Also I had enough of my reset password system so I made it easier for myself and cut most of it out. Now a user enters their email address, if a match is found then a temp password is generated using random_string(alnum 8) and then it is encrypted, salted , hashed etc and put into database. User can then log in with this temp password and keep it or change it.

Comment: I was thinking maybe suggest in the email that they change it if they want but either way I don't think it really matters. I've seen many sites doing it this way for years and still running till this day.

Comment: There are other ways I can do it like doing a match uri segment process like what I did with my account activation system then having them forward to a page that asks them to enter a new password if the uri matches and clears itself from the database. I guess as my site grows I can come back and improve things to make it better.

Answer (score 1):

I just made a [detailed blog post](http://jondavidjohn.com/code-design/codeigniter-login-system) about this exact topic, covering how to construct your "protected" controllers and at the same time define a global `$the_user` variable that is available both in all protected controllers and views.

I will try to compile a summary for this answer but until then, checkout [my post](http://jondavidjohn.com/code-design/codeigniter-login-system).

Comment: it's really the second and third section you're looking for... again, if i understood your question properly.

Answer (score 0):

Add the function into [a model](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html) , then you can load the model in different controllers when you need it . Please read the documentation .

---

Example

```
class User_model extends Model {

    function User_model()
    {
        parent::Model();
    }

    function get_user_by_email($email)
    {
     .....
    }
}
```

Save this to application/models/user_model.php , then in any of you're controller you can call :

```
$this->load->model('user_model');
$user_data = $this->user_model->get_user_by_email('me@example.com');
```

Then play with user data how you like

Comment: example found in the link , click "a model" or here http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/models.html

Comment: `$this->user_model->get_user_by_email` should be `$this->User_model->get_user_by_email` (Models start with an uppercase letter)

Answer (score 0):

Hands down the easiest way would be to store that information in a cookie/session. Typically I store the users email, name, and user_id. I of course encrypt the information stored in the cookie/session as well :)